# Calling Entity frameworks file from Exe, normally a part of a web service

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a older webservice, which uses Entity frameworks 6 to connect to Database.

The project is split up into web-service (controller) and "repository", which operated the database.

The idea is to now create an EXE which calls the repository, hence class library, which uses Entity framework. However, here I have some settings issues with connecting to the database.

The repository's config holds connection data, but for some reason it cannot connect.

Running is a default, hence default setting (none) of my exe, I get this error:

I can debug in into

```
    public partial class My_TestEntities : DbContext
    {
        public My_TestEntities()
            : base("name=My_TestEntities")
        {
        }
```

It crashes at that moment.
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." - which points to something deeper that just this.

I try to copy default into my own app.config

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="my_TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://..... stuff here..." />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings />
```

This results in
"The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception."

Copying the full config from the repository, some web stuff etc results in the same

Copying the configuration from the controller results in same as well.

I tried those things as I don't know what to do. I googled and found nothing.
So maybe here I can get some good ideas

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this myself.
The parent exe calling the repository needs to have Entity framework (nuget package) installed, this will add some parts automatically to the config, as above.

Next, only the connection string is needed in the config file.

Then it works